# The hanging of lead weights in the Cavendish experiment of 1798

Tags: stresses, strength

I'm working to build the Cavendish experiment of 1798 according to Cavendish's own specifications. I have a question about the hanging of the 150 kg lead weights.

[image: lead weights]

As seen in the image, there is a copper rod passing through the lead sphere. Cavendish does not indicate how thick this copper rod is. From the image I measured it as 1 cm diameter.

But now I think that a copper rod of 1 cm diameter may be too thin to carry a 150 kg sphere.

Is the thickness good and how can I compute the right thickness?

The diameter of the sphere is 30 cm.

The weights will be moved from one side of the small balls to the other side. So the copper rode must be able to stay firm and not wobble.

You can see the cross section of the experiment [here](http://cavendish-deneyi.com/parcalar.html) (the first image).

Comment: Did you check the tables for the tensile strength of copper?

Comment: No. I looked now. On this [site](https://www.matweb.com/search/datasheet_print.aspx?matguid=9aebe83845c04c1db5126fada6f76f7e)  for copper Tensile Strength, Ultimate  210 MPa. How do I compute how much weight a rod of 1 cm can carry from this data?

Answer (score 1):

Google says [210 Mpa = 2141 kg/cm<sup>2</sup>](https://www.google.com/search?q=210+mpa+to+kg%2Fcm2).

Without bothering to calculate the CSA (cross-sectional area) of a 1 cm diameter rod (it's π/4 cm<sup>2</sup>) I estimate that it gives you a safety factor of 10.

Comment: I looked up safety factor. If I understand correctly, you are saying that 1 cm copper rod could even carry a load of 1500 kg. Is this correct? If so, I’m safe?

Comment: What is CSA? There many different meanings online.

Comment: CSA = cross-sectional area. (That's why the units are $cm^2$.) If it was good enough for Cavendish it should be good enough for you.

Comment: Thanks. That’s true but he does not give the diameter of the rods, I calculate from the cross section drawing by proportion and this method does not always give accurate results.

Comment: How is this computed usually? I mean, the load that a given cross section can carry? If it’s not too difficult can you sketch it, just out of curiosity.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WUEDPfjPHlg